# cakephp $this->params not set in beforeFilter

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3, parameters

I needed to do something with $this->params in the `AppController::beforeFilter()` I get `Notice (8): Undefined variable: a` but when I set it in `beforeFilter()` the `b` variable is set normally. Is this normal behavior? And if it isn't, how do I get the params to be set in `beforeFilter()`? It would have been better if I could work with the params before any action is called.

```
function beforeFilter() {
$this->set('a', $this->params);
}

function beforeRender() {
$this->set('b', $this->params);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I had overriden `beforeFilter` in an controller and forgot to call `parent::beforeFilter()` at the start. Now it's ok.